# What is the xml:lang attibute of XHTML 1.0 means?

Tags: html, xhtml

Here is XHTML 1.0 Transitinal DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

following the xml namespace attribute,can I change the xml:lang and lang to another value,such as other language?how it works?Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `xml:lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-lang-tag) is simply the `lang` attribute that corresponds to XML itself (`xml` being its namespace). Since XHTML derives from XML, elements in an XHTML document must have the `xml:lang` attribute, along with the HTML `lang` attribute. You usually just declare `xml:lang` on the `<html>` opening tag and everything else inside will "inherit" the language value appropriately.

If you need to specify a different language, make sure to specify the same value for both attributes.

This is stated in the [XHTML 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_7):

> Use both the `lang` and `xml:lang` attributes when specifying the language of an element. The value of the `xml:lang` attribute takes precedence.